# What is an effective means to educate non-academic colleagues of the importance and time needed for Adjunct Lecturing research?

Tags: independent-researcher, adjunct-faculty

My situation is, I am an Adjunct Lecturer (Physics); however, to support myself, I work full-time as a high school teacher.  Essentially, the situation is that an Adjunct Lecturer is working amongst non-academic colleagues, who unfortunately see the research as nothing more than a 'hobby'.

What is an effective means of helping these non-academic colleagues comprehend the importance and time-needed for the research involved with being an Adjunct Lecturer?

Comment: Would you classify yourself as not having an institutional affiliation (for research purposes)? If so, add the [tag:independent-researcher] tag, since, I think this is a problem faced by many unaffiliated researchers.

Comment: Yes, I certainly do have an institutional affiliation, thank you for that - tag added!

Comment: For one thing, in my experience, the post of "adjunct lecturer" is usually one whose duties are only teaching, so if you have research responsibilities as well, I can understand people not being aware of that.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually my duties are entirely research and no teaching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NateEldredge mentioned, technically research is probably not part of the duties of an Adjunct Lecturer.

That being said, you could explain that as an adjunct it is natural for you to develop your CV further so that you may be considered for teaching higher-level courses, increase in rank, service on interesting committees, etc., in which case research will be important.

Comment: I've never seen an adjunct lecturer get promotions or committee posts in the US. (Only a few get to even teach upper-division courses.) Is this common in your area?

Comment: @shane how about making that a Question?